# How to wrap a call to a native promise in a react native javascript API?

Tags: javascript, objective-c, react-native

Cannot figure out the proper way to define a js API wrapper for a native promise created for react native (mainly following [the original docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-ios.html#promises)). Defining the native function like this:

```
RCT_REMAP_METHOD(getMyPromise,
                  getMyPromiseResolver:(RCTPromiseResolveBlock)resolve
                  rejecter:(RCTPromiseRejectBlock)reject)
{
  NSString *result = @"Kept!";
  if (result) {
    resolve(result);
  } else {
    reject(@"no_status", @"My promise failed",
            [NSError errorWithDomain:@"MyModule" code:200 userInfo:nil]);
  }
}
```

Accessing the native function directly works without any problems (as given in [the example in the docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-ios.html#promises)):

```
var NativeRNMyModule = require('NativeModules').RNMyModule;

async function localGetMyPromise() {
  try {
    var result = await NativeRNMyModule.getMyPromise();
    console.log("MyPromise kept: ", result);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log("MyPromise rejected: ", e.message);
  }
}
localGetMyPromise();
```

However, since I have a javascript wrapper API for all my other functions in `index.js` of the module, I would like to have one also for native promises. I've been through a few dozen iterations, this being the simplest one:

```
var NativeRNMyModule = require('NativeModules').RNMyModule;

var RNMyModule = {
  getMyPromise: async function() {
    NativeRNMyModule.getMyPromise();
  }};

module.exports = RNMyModule;
```

Other iterations include adding an `await` before the call to `NativeRNMyModule.getMyPromise();` as well as creating a completely new intermediate promise. Even with the simplest approach the returned promise-functions directly and through the wrapper look otherwise identical on the console , but the one coming through the wrapper has return value `undefined`. Consequently, the result of querying through the wrapper is also `undefined`.

What is the best way to create a working pass-through wrapper for a promise?

Comment: Tagging Objective-C might help.

Comment: Done. However, since everything appears to work by skipping the javascript wrapper, I wouldn't expect to find a solution in Objective-C.